# Explanation of ordered set

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology by munkres in that;I read order topology but i can't clearly understand what an ordered set is. can someone explain it in a very clear way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A,\mathcal R)$ is an order set if $\mathcal R$ is an order on $A$. Take for exemple $(\mathbb N,\mid)$ where $\mid$ is the divisibility. This is an order set. But this set is not totally ordered since there is element that are not comparable (like for exemple $3$ and $5$.) In other word, an ordered set is a set where elements are comparable (but all element are not necessarily comparable). A total ordered set is a set where **all** elements are comparable.

It's complicate to give a better answer since the question is at least very very general...

Comment: can you give some link to read it

Comment: google is your friend ;-)